# Access files using using Phonegap 3.3.0 for ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to work with files on IOS, using Phonegap[cordova 3.3.0]. I read how to access files and read them on the API Documentation of phone gap. also added plugin like this

```
  $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
    $ cordova plugin ls
    [ 'org.apache.cordova.file' ]
    $ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file

 $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
    $ cordova plugin ls
    [ 'org.apache.cordova.file',
      'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer' ]
    $ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

function gotFS(fileSystem)  is not calling after  onDeviceReady() function.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
       function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);
    readAsText(file);
}

function readDataUrl(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as data URL");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

This code is working for android. But for Ios, I am getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: LocalFileSystem
in this line -

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

Comment: Do you actually listen to the deviceready event to call the onDeviceReady function? Did you try to add console.log at each step to be sure what's called or not?

Comment: yes deviceready event is calling .
this line have some problem
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

Comment: This code is working for android. But for Ios, I am getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: LocalFileSystem
in this line -

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

Comment: lines you show about plugin installation contain "cordova plugin rm", I hope you didn't run it. also how are you launching your project?

Comment: yes, I did not run cordova plugin rm.As rm for remove so didn't run that line.
I am lunching project to device(ipad).

Comment: sorry not an expert with ios plugins, so maybe my last attempt to help... are you running the project with the cli or with xcode? if you are using xcode, maybe you forgot to run cordova prepare ios to install the plugin in the platforms/ios folder?

Comment: I am running in xcode. and I run cordova prepare ios.

Answer (score 2):

If LocalFileSystem isn't defined, it almost certainly means that the plugin's JavaScript code isn't being loaded.

Are you using any other Cordova APIs? Can you tell if cordova.js is being loaded from your HTML page and whether it runs correctly?

On iOS, one of the best debugging techniques for a problem like this is to connect to the iPad (or simulator) with Safari, and run

```
location.reload()
```

from the JavaSCript console. If cordova.js encounters an error, then it may stop running before it gets to loading the File plugin.

(FWIW, LocalFileSystem was never supposed to be a real object; it's actually an interface, which `window` is supposed to implement. I would switch to using `window.PERSISTENT` for compatibility with the File API spec. That said, Cordova (for backwards compatibility) should be setting the PERSISTENT and TEMPORARY symbols on both `window` and `LocalFileSystem`.)

Comment: I am using cordova3.3.0.  coedova.js is loading properly, Because onDeviceReady() function is calling.

Comment: yes it may stop running before it gets to loading the File plugin. what may be reason of stop.

Comment: Have you tried the `location.reload()` trick I mentioned? If it stops running, then there should be an error in the console that you can see there.

Comment: $ sudo npm install -g phonegap
    



Usage
$ phonegap create my-app
$ cd my-app
$ phonegap run android

Comment: Beside cordova. I also install phonegap like bellow command. and make new application and install all plugin. Now file read write program  is working.
Thank You for help .

$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
$ phonegap create my-app
$ cd my-app

Comment: I had a similar error, using Cordova and Ionic. This response helped solve it. It had nothing to do with LocalFileSystem and everything to do with cordova.js. I ran "cordova platform update ios" and it fixed the cordova bug.

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap 3.3.0's Filesystem has a new approach. If you have been using fullpath for entry, you need to replace that with toURL().

Also in your config.xml file you got to add

```
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Your best bet would be to go over this link https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Making these changes worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Where did you get this info? In the official PhoneGap docs there's nothing about ios Persistent File Location.

Comment: The link you posted 404s.

Answer (score 0):

Beside cordova. I also install phonegap [like bellow command](http://phonegap.com/install/). and make new application and install all plugin. Now file read write program is working. 
Thank You for help .

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap 
$ phonegap create my-app 
$ cd my-app
```