# Cordova requestFileSystem is no longer being loaded 3.4.1

Tags: android, cordova

I recently updated to Cordova 3.4.1 I then proceeded to build and test my project and found it had issues. I have spent that last day and a half trying to revert and rebuild the project so that it works. Nothing i have tried thus far has worked.

Error im getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'requestFileSystem'
```

Code used to produce this error:

```
var app = {
    appRoot: 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/',
    init: function(){
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function(that){
        //location.reload(true);
        console.log(Object.keys(window));
        console.log(Object.keys(cordova));
        window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){
            console.log('we have a fs');
            fs.root.getFile(dir+file,{create:true, exclusive: false},function(fileEntry){
                console.log('we have a file entry');
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(evt){
                    success(evt.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsText(dir+file);
            },fail);
        },fail);
    }
};
function fail(e){
    var msg = '';

    switch (e.code) {
      case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
        msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
        msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
        msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
        break;
      case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
        msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
        break;
      default:
        msg = 'Unknown Error';
        break;
    };

    console.log('Error: ' + msg);
 }

 app.init();
```

What Ive tried:

- Ive tried using the following Cordova versions 3.3.1, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.5.0
- Ive tried using older version of the file api 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0
- I have tried creating a new project from scratch
- I have tried building using api version 17, 19
- I have tried testing on an android 4.2.2 and 4.4.2

I have verified that the plugin is loaded into the project, and that it gets built onto the device. Im using the `monitor.bat` that comes with the Android SDK to watch console events and errors and the requestFileSystem is just not being injected.

I have tried using( as suggested by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283256/access-files-using-using-phonegap-3-3-0-for-ios)):

```
location.reload()
```

and

```
location.reload(true) //not from cache
```

to see if there was errors with the cordova plugin initialization but there was nothing.

**Does anyone have any more suggestions on what could fix this issue?**

Comment: What is the specific error(s) you get?

Comment: I updated the question with the error and a code sample

Comment: What's in your `this.loadConfig` method? Also, it'll be `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT`, not `window.PERSISTENT`.

Comment: LocalFileSystem is only set if the plugin ACTUALLY gets loaded, window.PERSISTENT is always available so i was just using that to reduce the number of errors received. As for the loadConfig method it was a typo it should have been(and has been corrected to `onDeviceReady`)

Comment: Yeah -- no, don't use `window.PERSISTENT`. You can't guarantee that the value of that particular constant is the same as `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT`. It *probably* is, but there's no guarantee it will always be that way. As long as you wait until `deviceReady`, the plugin is loaded, and all its constants should be loaded.

Comment: Also, you aren't calling `this.onDeviceReady` correctly -- your current method is calling it and passing the return result (whatever that is) to `addEventListener`. It should instead be this like this: `document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);` If you *must* pass a parameter like a specific `this`, use `bind`, like this: `document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);` (but you really shouldn't need to do the latter if you're doing things right).

Comment: So the code was getting executed before the device was actually ready? why is that?

Comment: It looks like fixing the event listener call solved the issue, add that as an answer and ill mark it solved! Thank you so much

Comment: Added as an answer. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually calling `deviceReady` too soon. In this line:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady(this), false);
```

the *return result* of `onDeviceReady` is being passed to `addEventListener`, which isn't your intent, and means it gets called well before any plugins are initialized.

Better to do this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

If you *must* pass `this` (or another parameter) along, do this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
```

But you shouldn't really have to do that, assuming you're setting your object up correctly.